# Конструктор портала управления данными в базе данных?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, база-данных

Дано:
Интернет магазин (на самом деле, все сложнее, но для осознания сути вопроса — пойдет).
50 таблиц со всевозможными связями (в основном «один ко многим»).
Клиенты, Субклиенты (аффилиэйт сеть), Поставщики, Товары, Покупки (+Возвраты, +Замены), Цены разных поставщиков, Курсы валют, Схемы поставок и т.д. и т.п.

Сейчас все это работает через сторонний софт, в который выгружаются все продажи... там формируются отчеты и уже откуда все валится в 1С.
Задача заменить вот это промежуточное звено. Т.е. нужен некий конструктор, в который можно зайти, создать нужные страницы (разделы) с выгружаемыми данными из нужных таблиц (подтягивая человекопонятные названия из, скажем, других таблиц-справочников и т.д.), создать нужные формы для добавления/редактирования записей в БД.

Сейчас в качестве БД использует Oracle. Мы думаем на нем же и остаться (львиная доля логики реализована как Хранимые процедуры и Тригеры), но как «План Б» — Postgres. Вопрос в интерфейсе.
Бизнесс-логику перепишем — не проблема. Сейчас стоит задача анализа возможных вариантов организации. Клиентский портал реализован (собственноручно) — нужен бэкофис (теперь уже тоже собственноручный).
Можем написать сами. Но для начала хотели бы реализовать новую схему работы через конструктор (по тому и отказываемся от текущего ПО — разработчик тупо отказал в переделаках), а уже после — перепишем «на чистовик».

*Присматриваемся в сторону Oracle WebCenter Portal 12c:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/portal/overview/index.html
...у Oracle столько продуктов, что глаза разбегаются... может есть что-то более подходящее и мы просто проглядели?*

По большому счету, окошки как у 1С с «таблицами» — самое то. Список заказов... кликая на заказ — открывается небольшое окошко поверх со всей информацией о заказе и возможностью редактирования... далее, по клику на контрагенте — окошко с контрагентом и т.д.
+ авторизация и роли. Кто, что может смотреть/редактировать/добавлять...
= идеально.

Многого хочу? Или есть подобные «конструкторы»? Web или desktop — не имеет значения. Коннект напрямую с базой — без проблем.

PS. Всю выгрузку в 1С сделаем сами (уже сделали) — нужен визуализатор и редактор...

[image]
<sub>(источник: [adm-1c.ru](http://www.adm-1c.ru/products/ut81/UT10-1920.jpeg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Если еще актуально - рекомендую Oracle Application Express, он же APEX, он же апекс.
Попробовать можно тут: http://apex.oracle.com. Продукт бесплатный, но очень мощный, отдаленно напоминает MS Access.